# AWS SQS Socket Hang up Intermittent error

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I keep receiving this error sometimes when trying to receive messages from SQS queue in my lambda

```
2019-07-19T13:10:17.371Z    03b1cea1-0266-45b0-9b54-1fbe561e148a    ERROR   { Error: socket hang up
at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:323:15)
at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:426:23)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:194:15)
at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1125:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

Here's my code

```
const sqs = new AWS.SQS({apiVersion: '2012-11-05'});

module.exports.processEvent = thundra((event, context, callback) => {

      let params = {
        QueueUrl: queueUrl,
        MaxNumberOfMessages : 10
      };

      sqs.receiveMessage(params).promise().then(res => {
        if(res.Messages) {
          return Promise.all(res.Messages.map(doWork));
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err, err.stack))
      .then(() => context.succeed())
      .catch(err => context.fail(err, err.stack));
    });
```

Any idea what's happening?

Here are the few things I've already tried

- I've tried changing the nodejs runtime from v8 to v10. That didn't help
- I've tried playing around with the timeout setting in my serverless.yml for this lambda function - tried 10 seconds, 20 seconds. Didn't help
- I've tried long polling by specifying "WaitTimeSeconds" attribute and playing around with its value from 20 seconds to 10 seconds and finally by completely removing it from my code

Nothing has helped so far. Also it's important to know that this error only happens sometimes. Not every time.

Comment: Hi Saumil, Does this error happen when you use callback() instead of context.succeed() and callback(err) instead of context.fail(err, errr.stack)?

Comment: yes..even after replacing context.succeed() with callback, I still see an issue. It seems to be an issue caused by Thundra wrapper I'm using. I've gone ahead and set the ENV variable thundra_agent_lambda_trace_disable to true and I'm going to keep an eye on it to see if that improves.